# Prefetching some data when the App is in the background

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I know quite a few questions have been asked around this topic; however, am penning this as they don't seem to specifically answer my question, & some don't have any correct answer listed.

**What I want to do in my iPhone App**
Fetch some data when the App is not running (basically, it's a prefetch, so as to quicken it when the user uses the App the next time). What's the best way to do this?

**Some Potential Solutions**
Those that I could think of & some from Stackoverflow & such resources:

**Possibility 1** : Fetch the data at a specific time of the day (maybe after midnight ?). Am not seeing 'clearly' how to do this if this this possible in the first place. Some suggest using a **NSTimer** -> but the timer is put off when the application is suspended, right?

**Possibility 2** :  Using **local notification** (?) But I see that Apple's documentation specifically mentioning that notification is to be used to convey something to the user & so this would defy Apple's doc then, right?

**Possibility 3** : Through applicationDidEnterBackground -> **beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler** . This wouldn't run the fetch at a specific time of the day though. However, it might serve its purpose of 'pre'-fetching. Is this better than the other two?

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 1):

as you already know that none of the option you have presented are not going to work with ios and user can always close the background applications anyway so I would suggest that it'd be a good idea to fetch the data for next calendar day whenever the app is running.

Answer (score 1):

As samfisher is saying none of your specs. fit with the Apple active background requirements. The only thing that I can suggest you is to use the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`  I understand that is a "post fetching" instead of prefetching but I guess is the only way.
The other way, but is a little bit trickier, is masquerade your prefetching with some sort of geolocation, in this way you could opt for an active background. This involve a lot of aspects such as:

- Appstore rejection
- Battery consumption

There are plenty of app on the appstore that use this trick, I can remember one that calculate data traffic.

Comment: +1 Thank you! Yes, I too think I should comply with Apple doc to avoid rejection. So the best bet seems to be beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler .